# keras.utils.Sequence- object is not an iterator

Tags: python, keras

```py
class CIFAR10Sequence(Sequence):

    def __init__(self, x_set, y_set, batch_size):
        self.x, self.y = x_set, y_set
        self.epoch = 0
        self.batch = 0
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.per = 4

    def __len__(self):
        return int(np.ceil(len(self.x) / float(self.batch_size)))

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        batch_x = self.x[int(np.ceil(self.x.shape[0]*(self.per/100)))]
        batch_y = self.y[int(np.ceil(self.x.shape[0]*(self.per/100)))]
        return np.array(batch_x), np.array(batch_y)
        return (batch_x, batch_y)

    def on_batch_end(self):
        if self.epoch % 100 == 0:
            self.per = self.per*1.9
        self.epoch += 1

train_datagen = CIFAR10Sequence(new_x_sort, new_x_sort, 100)
test_datagen = CIFAR10Sequence(cifar100_dataset.x_test,
                               cifar100_dataset.x_test, 100)

model.fit_generator(generator=train_datagen, steps_per_epoch=len(new_x_sort)//100, epochs=20)
```

but I get:

`TypeError: 'CIFAR10Sequence' object is not an iterator`

Comment: Did you find a correct solution?

Answer (score 0):

You need `__iter__()` function in `CIFAR10Sequence`.
Something like

```py
def __iter__(self):
    self.cur_idx += 1
    return self[self.cur_idx]
```

Comment: Doesn't an iterable also have to implement a `__next__` method?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the Sequence object must have been referenced in another context before you got to the fit_generator call. That call doesn't take a keyword arg for the generator, so you would get keyword arg error if you did reach that call. The Sequence object does have `__iter__()` so it's iterable, but it doesn't have `__next__()` so it's not an iterator and if it was referenced as such it would throw that error. `__iter__()` is all that's needed for keras fit.